# Some calculation in Mahan book, p73

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, greens-functions, many-body, s-matrix-theory

On page 73 of Mahan, *Many-particle physics*, 3rd edition, one finds

$$
_0\langle|S(-\infty,0) = e^{-iL}_0\langle|S(\infty,-\infty)S(-\infty,0).
$$

I'm wondering why this is true, as in the previous page the book *defines* $|\rangle_0 = \phi_0$ and on page 71 one finds

$$
\phi_0 e^{iL} = S(\infty,-\infty)\phi_0.
$$

In braket notation, the above expression is

$$
e^{iL}|\rangle_0 = S(\infty,-\infty)|\rangle_0
$$
and
$$
_0\langle|e^{-iL} = _0\langle|S^\dagger(\infty,-\infty) = _0\langle|S(-\infty,\infty)
$$
will not yield the expression in the book. Am I wrong in something or the book as an erratum??

Comment: What is $L$, what is $S$, what is $\phi_0$?

Comment: They come from the book... Although they don't matter much what they are as my question is regarding the algebra (and if indeed there is a typo in the book).

Comment: But if you want the meaning, fine: One considers a system with a Hamiltonian $H=H_0 + V$, in which one knows the solution for $H_0$. The state $\phi_0$ represents the ground state of $H_0$. $S$ is the S-matrix used in many-particle physics in the computation of Green's functions, $S(t,t')=U(t)U^\dagger(t')$, where $U$ is the operator that transforms the problem into the interaction picture. $L$ is just a phase (as is obvious from the context) and relates the wave function of the full system in the interaction picture $\hat{\psi}(t)$ via the property $\hat{\psi}(\infty) = S(\infty,0)\psi(0)$

Comment: where $\psi(t)$ is the wavefunction of the full system in the Scröndinger picture. It is assumed that the Gell-Mann and Low theorem holds s.t. $\psi(0) = S(0,-\infty)\phi_0$ and therefore the property mentioned above is $\phi_0 e^{iL} = S(\infty,-\infty)\phi_0$.
I might add that the question is really for those people that have worked with the book, hence the question's title.

Comment: Please port these explanatory comments up into the body of your question if you get a chance.... But, anyways, I answered. You need to do a little more manipulation using the rules and definitions from the previous couple pages...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> On page 73 of Mahan, *Many-particle physics*, 3d edition, one finds
>
> $$
> _0\langle|S(-\infty,0) = e^{-iL}_0\langle|S(\infty,-\infty)S(-\infty,0).
> $$
>
> I'm wondering why this is true, as in the previous page the book *defines* >$|\rangle_0 = \phi_0$ and on page 71 one finds
>
> $$
> \phi_0 e^{iL} = S(\infty,-\infty)\phi_0.
> $$
>
> In braket notation, the above expression is
>
> $$
> e^{iL}|\rangle_0 = S(\infty,-\infty)|\rangle_0
> $$
> and
> $$
> _0\langle|e^{-iL} = _0\langle|S^\dagger(\infty,-\infty) = _0\langle|S(-\infty,\infty)
> $$
> will not yield the expression in the book...

I'm going to write $|0\rangle$ not $|\rangle_0$, since it is easier.
Anyways, continuing from your last expression above...
$$
e^{-iL}\langle 0 | = \langle 0|S(-\infty, \infty)
$$

Multiply both sides by $e^{+iL}$ and multiply from the right by $S(\infty,-\infty)$ to find:
$$
\langle 0 |S(\infty,-\infty) = e^{+iL}\langle 0 |S(-\infty,\infty)S(\infty,-\infty) = e^{+iL}\langle 0|
$$
to arrive at
$$
\langle 0 | = e^{-iL}\langle 0|S(\infty,-\infty)\;,\tag{A}
$$
which is the equation you are looking for.

Thus, returning to page 73 and using Eq. (A) above:
$$
\langle 0 |S(-\infty, 0) = e^{-iL}\langle 0|S(\infty,-\infty)S(-\infty, 0)
$$
$$
=e^{-iL}\langle 0|S(\infty, 0)
$$
$$
=\frac{\langle 0|S(\infty, 0)}{\langle 0 |S(\infty,-\infty)|0\rangle}\;.
$$